# handle multiple text boxes in php

Tags: php, html

I have a dynamic rows coming from the database. each row has an order field. I want to make the user able to change the order by entering the order in text boxes show's next to each row, and when the user click save each row will be updated with the new order.

My problem is when I wrote this code:

```
    <table>
    <?
    foreach($results as $p)
    {
        echo '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$p['page_title'].'</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="2" id="'.$p['page_id'].'" name="s[]" value="'.$p['menu_order'].'"></td>
        </tr>';
    }
    ?>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save Order"></td></tr>
    </table>
```

as you can see that every dynamic text box would give the the new order after posting the form, **but the Question is how I can know this order to which row ?**

the image would explain more. After I clicked Save the `s` array would be like this:

Array ( [0] => 2 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVdBd.jpg) => 3 [2] => 1 )

However, I cannot know the page that I want to update !! 
[image]

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "Question is how I can know this order to which row ?"

Comment: so the array (S) would have an array with the new orders right? However, I don't know this order belong to what ?

Comment: can you see the image above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to order the fields by the number assigned to it. If that's what you are looking to do and if you are using MySQL to store this data you can just retreive it in that order. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY menu_order ASC
```

**Edit:** Now that I have re-read your question you also might be asking how to assign that order to each row. I noticed that your fields are named `s[]` You could name them `$p['page_id']` and update them accordingly.

```
 <?
    foreach($results as $p)
    {
        echo '
            <tr>
            <td>'.$p['page_title'].'</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="2" id="'.$p['page_id'].'" name="s['.$p['page_id'].']" value="'.$p['menu_order'].'"></td>
        </tr>';
    }
    ?>
```

And then

```
foreach($_POST['s'] as $key => $value) {
    // Update each $key with $value
    // Where $key is the ID and $value is the order
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I mean the orders from the array `s` would have the new orders. However, I couldn't find any way to find the menu_id so i can update it with the new order.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you :D